# How to access custom error object thrown by npm module [Error: [object Object]]

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, error-handling

An npm module generates an error of this format.

```
throw new Error(error.data.errors)
```

where `error.data.errors` is

```
{ email: [ 'is invalid' ] }
```

When I try to access it in the catch block of my code, it comes up as

```
[Error: [object Object]]
```

How can I access the original error / error message from my catch block?

Comment: Could you post the code where you're catching the error, please?

Comment: do not throw the Error. Handle it. Return it using callback. Then you can access it as POJO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did some experimentation and there doesn't seem to be a lot you can do in this case. It looks like JavaScript calls `.toString()` on the error message when it's thrown. By default, this is `"[object Object]"` on all objects.

As far as I can tell, the fix would be to open a pull request that changed the throwing of the error to the following:

```
throw new Error(JSON.stringify(error.data.errors));
```

With this change, you could parse the JSON upon catching the error.

```
try {
  // Whatever functionality causes the error.
} catch (e) {
  var errors = JSON.parse(e.message);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I've submitted a PR and it was accepted. Able to access the error now.